# Concatenate rows of two dimensional list elements in a list

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, multiple-columns

I want to reorganize two-dimensional list elements in a list (here two elements):

```
[[['A','B','C'], 
  ['G','H','I']], 
 [['D','E','F'], 
  ['J','K','L']]]
```

to become:

```
[['A','B','C','D','E','F'], 
 ['G','H','I','J','K','L']]
```

Is there a better way to write this, than the one expressed by the following function?

```
def joinTableColumns(tableColumns):
    """
    fun([[['A','B','C'], 
          ['G','H','I'] ], 
         [['D','E','F'], 
          ['J', 'K', 'L']]]) --> [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 
                                  ['G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']]
    """
    tableData = []

    for i,tcol in enumerate(tableColumns):

        for j,line in enumerate(tcol):
            if i == 0:
                tableData.append(line)
            else:
                tableData[j]+=line

    return tableData
```

Considering, that the number of rows to join is equal:

```
tdim_test = [(len(x), [len(y) for y in x][0] )for x in tableData]

len(list(set([x[0] for x in tdim_test])))==1
```

How can I increase robustness of that function? Or, is there something from a standard library that I should use instead?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function and [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) within a list comprehension:

```
In [17]: lst = [[['A','B','C'], 
                 ['G','H','I']], 
                [['D','E','F'], 
                 ['J','K','L']]]

In [18]: from itertools import chain

In [19]: [list(chain.from_iterable(i)) for i in zip(*lst)]
Out[19]: [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']]
```

Or as a pure functional approach you can use [`itertools.starmap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) and `operator.add()`:

```
In [22]: from itertools import starmap

In [23]: from operator import add

In [24]: list(starmap(add, zip(*lst)))
Out[24]: [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']]
```

Comment: Thanks! I prefere your first solution, but the second one is also nice!

Comment: @skidzo Note that the benefit of using `itertools` functions is that beside a good performance they will give you an iterator which is very optimized in terms of memory use. So in both solutions you don't have to convert the sub-lists to list if you only want to iterate over them or use them in another context that it's not required for them to be list objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
import functools
[ functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x + y, i,[])  for i in zip(*matrix)]
```

This will give you what you want

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `zip` function, unpacking the table inside it and add the pairs:

```
table = [[['A','B','C'], ['G','H','I']], 
         [['D','E','F'], ['J','K','L']]]    
res = [t1 + t2 for t1, t2 in zip(*table)]
```

which yields your wanted result:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']]
```